# Angular 10 - MIME type Not Supported Issue

Tags: angular, mime-types, angular10, angular-upgrade

I recently upgraded my Angular Code from v4 to v10. When compiled and served on localhost the application run perfectly fine. But when deployed on server I do get below errors in console.

Can someone please guide what's going wrong here ?

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://***application-url****/AppAdmin/styles.c79c3cd328dbbfe66fea.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

index.html:34 GET https://***application-url****/AppAdmin/main.7fbf499127f0fe2c9336.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
index.html:34 GET https://***application-url****/AppAdmin/scripts.036e53363d78021c6b22.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
index.html:34 GET https://***application-url****/AppAdmin/runtime.acf0dec4155e77772545.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
index.html:34 GET https://***application-url****/AppAdmin/polyfills.aa90931459b684cafd4d.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I think (if my memory don't crash) that one of the changes from Angular 4 are the httpClient and another is the rxjs. You need check your calls to API

Comment: I don't think this is something related to my API's. These are the styles and other script files which the application isn't able to find when loading the application on browser.

Comment: in Angular 4 yuor'e using http, in Angular 5 and newer) you use httpClient, check [this link](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/steps-to-upgrade-angular-to-latest-version-from-versions-5-183f5fb661ec) for more info (No, you needn't change your API, only the way Angular comunnicatte with it)